# refreshing bound datagridview with filter after update c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, refresh

I have a datagridview with a filter for doing search. If I update the database and then reset the dgv to the datasource I lose my filter. I tried doing ResetBindings but that didn't help. If I close the form and reopen the changes are there, I'd just like it to happen in "real time". Any advice is appreciated.

I have a dataset based on a SQL view. In this dataset there is a table based on this view. The datagridview is bound to this table. I have several controls including textboxes and combo boxes which are bound to columns in the dgv. I have a textbox which is used to search on the grid:

```
private void txtFilterString_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolStripTextBox tb = (ToolStripTextBox)sender;

    DataView dv = tILEDataSet.vwTILEAdmin.DefaultView;

    vwTILEAdminBindingSource.Filter =
        string.Format(@"PdcProductName LIKE '%{0}%' OR LabelDescription LIKE '%{0}%' OR LabelProductName LIKE '%{0}%'",
        tb.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));

    dataGridView1.Refresh();                
}
```

After making changes to a row in the dgv by modifying one or more of the bound controls I save the changes, which update the table:

```
sql.Append(@"UPDATE [dbo].[LabeledProducts]
SET [PdcProductName] = @pdcProd
,[LabelProductName] = @lblProd
,[LabelDescription] = @lblDesc
,[Power] = @pwr
,[Fabrication] = 0
,[UL_File_Number] = ''
,[PrePrintedSerial] = 0
,[ShowOrderOnLabel] = 0
,[PrivateLabelLogoId] = @plid
,[AgencyImageId] = @aid
,[WireDiagConfigId] = @wid
WHERE PdcProductName = '").Append(pdcProductName).Append("'");

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), printConfigTableAdapter.Connection)) 
{
    if (vwTILEAdminTableAdapter.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        vwTILEAdminTableAdapter.Connection.Open();

    LabeledProductsDataTableAdapter.UpdateCommand = command;
    LabeledProductsDataTableAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdcProd", txtPdcProdName.Text);
    LabeledProductsDataTableAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lblProd", txtLabeledProd.Text);
    LabeledProductsDataTableAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lblDesc", txtLabelDesc.Text);
    LabeledProductsDataTableAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwr", txtPower.Text);
    // we need ulfilename and mod
    LabeledProductsDataTableAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plid", LogoId);
    LabeledProductsDataTableAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aid", AgencyId);
    LabeledProductsDataTableAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wid", WireId);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    int rowsAffected = LabeledProductsDataTableAdapter.Update(dt);
    rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    dataGridView1.Refresh();
    //dataGridView1.DataSource = tILEDataSet.vwTILEAdmin;

    //this.vwTILEAdminBindingSource.ResetBindings(true);

}
```

If I uncomment the line where I set the DataSource, I get a refreshed view, but the textbox used to generate the filter on the binding source no longer works, e.g. regardless of what I type in the textbox. The Text_Changed event does still get called, but the filter no longer has any affect on the contents of the dgv.

Comment: Please post your code first so that we can understand you problem clearly. What is filter?

Comment: vwTILEAdminBindingSource.Filter =
    string.Format(@"PdcProductName LIKE '%{0}%' OR LabelDescription LIKE '%{0}%' OR LabelProductName LIKE '%{0}%'",
    tb.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''"));

   dataGridView1.Refresh();

Comment: Sure. vwTILEAdminBindingSource.Filter = string.Format(@"PdcProductName LIKE '%{0}%' OR LabelDescription '%{0}%' OR LabelProductName LIKE '%{0}%'", tb.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''")); dataGridView1.Refresh(); then in the update code I tried calling Refresh again. Then, if I set the datasource of the grid again the search capability of the text box is gone. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your question with your current code and include some details about what sort of datasource you have (datatable?) and how you currently update it. The standard way of doing this is to null the datasource and then set it again - it isn't clear what you mean when you say "the search capability of the text box is gone"

Comment: I've managed to reproduce similar behaviour by creating a new DataTable when I add rows (I'm not using table adapters so just manually simulate an update). Not sure if this actually duplicates you problem though. Could you please post your full code behind, not just the filter and update methods. I think the issue must be that you are filtering on a table that is no longer your datasource but need to see where you instantiate everything to be sure. The line I think is suspect is DataTable dt = new DataTable(); I'd expect you to instead use a class level variable for dt.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your problem is something very simple.

In these lines:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = tILEDataSet.vwTILEAdmin; 

this.vwTILEAdminBindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
```

You set the data source of the grid to be vwTILEAdmin, but in your filter code you are filtering on the binding source which is no longer the data source of the grid!

Try instead:

```
this.vwTILEAdminBindingSource.DataSource = tILEDataSet.vwTILEAdmin; 

this.vwTILEAdminBindingSource.ResetBindings(true);
```

---

Also you probably don't need the `.Refresh()` calls on the grid - the method doesn't actually refresh a grid's data source. It only redraws the grid client area, and if you have a stale data source (where the grid doesn't know data has changed) the redraw won't make a difference.

If you are still having problems it could be that the update to the grids data source is not propogating - that is not raising the `ListChanged` event which the grid listens to to know when to update. If that is the case then you need to null the data source and reset it.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = typeof(List<string>); 
dataGridView1.DataSource = newDataSource;
```

In the code above the data source is set to `typeof(List)` since this keeps any existing columns. You would then set your binding source to the grid datasource again. Though I doubt this will be necessary - the binding source `ResetBindings` call should be enough.

Comment: Still not seeing the changes until I close the form and reopen, so I know the database is updating. I tried nulling out the data source and resetting it, to no affect. The line dataGridView1.DataSource = typeof(List); does not compile: Error 1 Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments. Thanks again for all your help @David.

Comment: @Gary yes, I just tried to duplicate your error and found that for me the filtering still works when I expected it to be broken. Going to keep digging to see if I can figure out what is different for you.

Comment: The filter continues to work, but the updated content isn't there until I reopen the form.

Comment: vwTILEAdminBindingSource.DataSource = tILEDataSet.vwTILEAdmin;
dataGridView1.DataSource = vwTILEAdminBindingSource;
vwTILEAdminBindingSource.ResetBindings(true); what am I missing?

Comment: @Gary it sounds like you have changed the code a little. Could you please edit your question with a complete winforms code behind that shows the minimal possible code to duplicate the issue. I don't have sql server on my current machine so need to see all the code to work out what is going on. That said have you tried to code in the comment with setting the datasource of the gridview to before resassigning the binding source?